# Query database table in Oracle on columns that are not indexed

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a database table in Oracle with a large amount of rows. When querying for a row two non-indexed columns are used. The query may take about 30 seconds to return.

Users send in a List of data-pairs so the query will use the first pair of data, plug it in the query and execute. To go through all data, the time to complete is quite long.

Example : if there are 20 data-pairs the time to complete will be 20 data-pairs*30 seconds = 600 seconds.

Can anyone recommend an approach that can reduce the amount of time to complete querying? If possible please post an example SQL.

Thank you

Comment: Add an index on those columns to avoid repeat full table scans. There is nothing else to do.

Comment: Thank you. however we don't own the tables and we are not allowed to modify it.

Comment: Tuning a query without seeing it (and table/index definitions) is somewhat akin to performing surgery over the telephone, so if the incision made by @Wolf didn't go well, you may also want to try "plugging" (whatever that means) the "list of data-pairs" all at once instead of "plugging" them one by one.

Comment: @mustaccio i know and i agree. imagine a simple query that says where fistname=? and lastname=? and this can take 30 seconds to return

Comment: I can even imagine such a query to never return, but that, I'm afraid, may not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substantially reduce the time by issuing just one query in which you get all rows matching any of the 20 pairs.

In that way, you'll have to scan the table just once instead of 20 times.

I would guess the query combining the 20 conditions will take 30 seconds, same as each individual query.

For example, you could create a temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_pairs
(
field1 int,
field2 int
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Then insert the pairs you receive:

```
insert into temp_pairs values (1,2);
insert into temp_pairs values (5,6);
```

Then query the original table with an inner join with the temp_pairs:

```
select t1.* from the_table t1
inner join temp_pairs t2
on t1.field1 = t2.field1
and t1.field2 = t2.field2;
```

Comment: Do you possibly have an small example you can post? for example, lets say data pars come in as [A,1] [B,2] [C,3], how can the query be written so rows will contain only the pairs mentioned?

Comment: I added a simple example.

Comment: cool, thank you. it seems that a temporary table(temp_pairs) will be needed for this query, correct?

Comment: This worked amazingly. From an average of 23 seconds to retrieve a single row, went in retrieving 300 rows in about 80 seconds. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an [expression list](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions016.htm#SQLRF52099):

```
select *
from table1
where (a, b) in ((1, 2), (3, 4) /*add more pairs here if necessary*/)
```

This is faster than the temporary table method, since no data needs to be inserted.  But it may require a little more code on the front end, to build a different query depending on the number of expressions.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Currently testing all approaches and measuring the timings.